# How to use a scope in combination with a Model method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, named-scope

I'm currently working on some scope filters, and I'd like to have it filter on a method (don't know how to name it otherwise). My code:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def price_with_discount
    price-discount.to_f
  end

  scope :by_price, lambda {|min,max|{ :conditions => { :price_with_discount => min.to_f..max.to_f }}}
end
```

This doesn't work: "No attribute named `price_with_discount` exists for table `products`". How can I trick my scope into using the method I defined instead of searching for a column named `price_with_discount`?

Bjorn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use ruby methods inside `:conditions`. This is not an exclusive scope thing, it applies in all ActiveRecord queries:

```
# This won't work either
Product.where(:price_with_discount => min.to_f)
```

The reason for this is that what ActiveRecord needs is something that can be "translated" into database fields. The symbol `:price_with_discount` can not be translated to the database.

Besides, if you are on rails 3, [you don't really need scopes any more](http://www.railway.at/2010/03/09/named-scopes-are-dead/). A regular class method will do the same, and it's easier to write (no lambdas).

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.by_price(min, max)
    # Assuming that products.discount is a database field:
    where([ "(products.price - products.discount) >= ? AND " +
            "(products.price - products.discount) <= ?",
            min, max
    ])
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I adjusted my code to something like your example, I'm on Rails 3, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't try to do a SQL restriction on our Ruby method. Avoid using it and I suppose it's works if your price-discount is not a String

```
scope :by_price, lambda {|min,max|{ :conditions => { :price-discount => min.to_f..max.to_f }}}
```